# Выделять оборот?

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

"Ты так отчаянно пытаешься скрыться от дискредитирующих тебя вопросов". Нужно ли отделять запятыми словосочетание "дискредитирующих тебя"? Насколько я знаю, подобные обороты не обособляются при утверждении, но все равно хочется удостовериться.

Answer (score 2):

Не нужно обособлять. Обособление понадобилось бы при ином порядке слов, если бы словосочетание стояло после определяемого: "Ты так отчаянно пытаешься скрыться от вопросов, дискредитирующих тебя".